# The center of an algebraic group over $\mathbb{Z}$ and over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G(\mathbb{Z})$ be a group identified with $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a set, where multiplication and inverse are given by polynomial maps.

We can think of $G(\mathbb{R})$ too, which is the group structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by the same polynomial maps.

Now, I wonder what happens to the center $Z(G)$ when we move from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I see that $Z(G(\mathbb{Z}))\otimes\mathbb{R}$ is contained in $Z(G(\mathbb{R}))$ because the "equation" $AX=XA$ for constant $A\in G(\mathbb{Z})$ is a polynomial equation, and so if it holds in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ it also holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Do we actually have an equality $Z(G(\mathbb{Z}))\otimes\mathbb{R}=Z(G(\mathbb{R}))$?

If not, does it help if we assume further that $G(\mathbb{Z})$ is contained in the group of upper triangular matrices (of some dimension) with $1$-s on the main diagonal? (i.e. "unipotent")

**Note**: I know next to nothing about algebraic groups and algebraic geometry. I tried to start, but it seems most texts work over algebraically closed fields, and certainly not over $\mathbb{Z}$. I did read "Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: Jantzen's book starts over an arbitrary ring, but I don't recall if it has anything specific about this. It might work out in this case since you are (as far as I can tell) considering group structures on affine $n$-space rather than more general schemes.